# Retrieve Info of SSL Certificate using Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

Im trying to check if a server has ssl certificate from iOS. Im not able to get that info and I can do it only through certificate pinning.
Is there any alternate to do this.
**Note**:
The SSL certificate is only available in server and is not present in app bundle.
Any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Well there is away where you can get the certificate from the server .cer file in other meaning just export it and attach it to your app bundle, if you are using AFNetworking, Alamofire, or NSURLSession then you can do the following to do SSL Pinning from your end:

I will assume that you are using NSURLSession then go with following code :

start by instantiating an NSURLSession object with the default session configuration.

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfig = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
self.urlSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfig delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
```

We will use the dataTaskWithURL:completionHandler: method for the SSL pinning test

```
[[self.urlSession dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.textField.text] completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        // response management code
    }] resume];
```

Now SSL pinning is implemented within the URLSession:didReceiveChallenge:completionHandler:delegate method. Note that, upon the creation of the NSURLSession object, we assigned self as the delegate so that this method is called on our object:

```
-(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session didReceiveChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSURLCredential * _Nullable))completionHandler {

    // Get remote certificate
    SecTrustRef serverTrust = challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust;
    SecCertificateRef certificate = SecTrustGetCertificateAtIndex(serverTrust, 0);

    // Set SSL policies for domain name check
    NSMutableArray *policies = [NSMutableArray array];
    [policies addObject:(__bridge_transfer id)SecPolicyCreateSSL(true, (__bridge CFStringRef)challenge.protectionSpace.host)];
    SecTrustSetPolicies(serverTrust, (__bridge CFArrayRef)policies);

    // Evaluate server certificate
    SecTrustResultType result;
    SecTrustEvaluate(serverTrust, &result);
    BOOL certificateIsValid = (result == kSecTrustResultUnspecified || result == kSecTrustResultProceed);

    // Get local and remote cert data
    NSData *remoteCertificateData = CFBridgingRelease(SecCertificateCopyData(certificate));
    NSString *pathToCert = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"github.com" ofType:@"cer"];
    NSData *localCertificate = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:pathToCert];

    // The pinnning check
    if ([remoteCertificateData isEqualToData:localCertificate] && certificateIsValid) {
        NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:serverTrust];
        completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeUseCredential, credential);
    } else {
        completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeCancelAuthenticationChallenge, NULL);
    }
}
```

A reference for AFNetworking, Alamofire, NSURLSession can be found here for [SSL Pinning](https://infinum.co/the-capsized-eight/how-to-make-your-ios-apps-more-secure-with-ssl-pinning)

**Note:** This method allow you to statically attaching the certificate to your app, you will need to update the app if the certificate expired, but mostly the certificate is for at least a couple of years.